# What is fragment?How to add a frgament to an existing activity?And how to modify layout of a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to android,and i want to create a fragment which has listview in it and i want to add that fragment to my main activity.I am trying but i cant add it to my activity and also cant define my own layout to it.So please help me.
Thanks in advance.

This is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.sample;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


String[] codeLearnChapters = new String[] { "Android Introduction","Android Setup/Installation","Android Hello World","Android Layouts/Viewgroups","Android Activity & Lifecycle","Intents in Android"};

ArrayAdapter<String> codeLearnArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, codeLearnChapters);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ListView codeLearnLessons = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.idListView1);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    codeLearnLessons.setAdapter(codeLearnArrayAdapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

And its xml is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


<fragment
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:name="com.example.sample.myFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My fragment java is myFragment.java

```
package com.example.sample;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater; 
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 * Created  on 11/4/2015.
*/
public class myFragment extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle
                                 savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.act_fragment,
            container, false);
    return view;
}
}
```

Its xml i.e act_fragment.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ListView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/idListView1">
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

Answer (score 1):

A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities. You can think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, which has its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you can add or remove while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub activity" that you can reuse in different activities).

In my words, a fragment is a sub-activity.

You can read more about what a fragment is http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

There is also a sample which you could use (and will be helpful as you will learn something new). The sample is http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

You can also look it up on youtube (once you have read about it and understood what fragment is). There is also a video tutorial to start you with. Just search "Android Fragment Lifecycle Part 1: Android Application Development Tutorial [HD 1080p]" - sorry, Stackoverflow is not allowing me to add more than two links.

They have five tutorials and I would recommend it as it will help you start better by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about what a fragment is
[link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)
Code :

```
public class Tab2Fragment extends Fragment {


    EditText fromdate;
    EditText todate;

    // List view 
    private ListView lv;

    // Listview Adapter 
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    // Search EditText 
    EditText inputSearch;


    // ArrayList for Listview 
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

    @Override 
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2_view, container, false);


        EditText fromdate=(EditText)V.findViewById(R.id.fromdate);
        EditText todate=(EditText)V.findViewById(R.id.todate);

        fromdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) {


            } 
        }); 

        // Listview Data 
        String products[] = {"Dell Inspiron", "HTC One X", "HTC Wildfire S", "HTC Sense", "HTC Sensation XE",
                "iPhone 4S", "Samsung Galaxy Note 800", 
                "Samsung Galaxy S3", "MacBook Air", "Mac Mini", "MacBook Pro"}; 

        lv = (ListView) V.findViewById(R.id.list_view);


        // Adding items to listview 
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);


        return V;
    } 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this link helpful you
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Place this in your activity class
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();

fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);

fragmentTransaction.commit();

and place below code in activitylayout code

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:id="@+id/fragment_container"

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```